# SQL Server 2019 - Update Table by JSON Array of object

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, open-json

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE WeeklySlots
    ([dow] int, [slots] int, [SlotCode] varchar(6))
;
    
INSERT INTO WeeklySlots
    ([dow], [slots], [slotCode])
VALUES
    (1, 0, 'T19_00'),
    (2, 20, 'T19_00'),
    (3, 20, 'T19_00'),
    (4, 20, 'T19_00'),
    (5, 20, 'T19_00'),
    (6, 20, 'T19_00'),
    (7, 20, 'T19_00'),
    (1, 0, 'T19_30'),
    (2, 20, 'T19_30'),
    (3, 20, 'T19_30'),
    (4, 20, 'T19_30'),
    (5, 10, 'T19_30'),
    (6, 10, 'T19_30'),
    (7, 20, 'T19_30'),
    (1, 0, 'T20_00'),
    (2, 20, 'T20_00'),
    (3, 20, 'T20_00'),
    (4, 20, 'T20_00'),
    (5, 10, 'T20_00'),
    (6, 10, 'T20_00'),
    (7, 20, 'T20_00'),
    (1, 0, 'T20_30'),
    (2, 20, 'T20_30'),
    (3, 20, 'T20_30'),
    (4, 20, 'T20_30'),
    (5, 20, 'T20_30'),
    (6, 20, 'T20_30'),
    (7, 20, 'T20_30');
```

then I need to update it with a `json` payload
(created with a pivot function from the above table)

```
@payload nvarchar(max)=N'[
   {
      "dow": 1,
      "T19_00": 10,
      "T19_30": 10,
      "T20_00": 10,
      "T20_30": 10
   },
   {
      "dow": 2,
      "T19_00": 20,
      "T19_30": 20,
      "T20_00": 20,
      "T20_30": 20
   },
   {
      "dow": 3,
      "T19_00": 20,
      "T19_30": 20,
      "T20_00": 20,
      "T20_30": 20
   },
   {
      "dow": 4,
      "T19_00": 20,
      "T19_30": 20,
      "T20_00": 20,
      "T20_30": 20
   },
   {
      "dow": 5,
      "T19_00": 20,
      "T19_30": 20,
      "T20_00": 20,
      "T20_30": 30
   },
   {
      "dow": 6,
      "T19_00": 20,
      "T19_30": 20,
      "T20_00": 20,
      "T20_30": 30
   },
   {
      "dow": 7,
      "T19_00": 20,
      "T19_30": 20,
      "T20_00": 20,
      "T20_30": 20
   }
]'
```

I understand how to parse it:

```
SELECT
    p2.*
from OPENJSON (@payload)
    WITH    (
                current_dow nvarchar(max) '$' as JSON
            )
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(current_dow)
    WITH 
    (
        [dow]       nvarchar(64)    '$.dow',
        [T19_00]    nvarchar(64)    '$.T19_00',
        [T19_30]    nvarchar(64)    '$.T19_30',
        [T20_00]    nvarchar(64)    '$.T20_00',
        [T20_30]    nvarchar(64)    '$.T20_30'  
    ) p2
```

but how can I update the WeeklySlots Table?
Do I need a recursive function?
Can suggest the right path to solve it?

PS: I made this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/caa86/2/0) to better explain the problem

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to parse the input `JSON` differently. Note, that when you use `OPENJSON()` with the default schema, the `key` column is an `nvarchar(4000)` value with a `BIN2` collation.

```
SELECT 
   CONVERT(int, JSON_VALUE(j1.[value], '$.dow')) AS dow, 
   CONVERT(int, j2.[value]) AS slots, 
   CONVERT(varchar(6), j2.[key] COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT) AS SlotCode
FROM OPENJSON(@payload) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) j2
WHERE j2.[key] <> N'dow'
```

The `UPDATE` statement is:

```
UPDATE ws
SET ws.slots = j.slots
FROM WeeklySlots ws
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT 
      CONVERT(int, JSON_VALUE(j1.[value], '$.dow')) AS dow, 
      CONVERT(int, j2.[value]) AS slots, 
      CONVERT(varchar(6), j2.[key] COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT) AS SlotCode
   FROM OPENJSON(@payload) j1
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) j2
   WHERE j2.[key] <> N'dow'
) j ON ws.dow = j.dow AND ws.SlotCode = j.SlotCode
```

Comment: Hmm.. a simple join... 
thanks also for the parsing.. actually in my version there was an "empty" OPENJSON, but did not know how to avoid it.
I try and let you know, thanks for the moment!

Answer (score 0):

You need to unpivot the JSON values into separate rows.

You can use another `OPENJSON` call, or if you know the names upfront you can do this using `CROSS APPLY (VALUES`

```sql
UPDATE WeeklySlots
SET slots = v.slots
FROM WeeklySlots ws
JOIN OPENJSON (@payload)
  WITH 
  (
    dow       int,
    T19_00    int,
    T19_30    int,
    T20_00    int,
    T20_30    int
  ) p
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES
      ('T19_00', p.T19_00),
      ('T19_00', p.T19_00),
      ('T19_00', p.T19_00),
      ('T19_00', p.T19_00)
  ) v(slotCode, slots)
  ON p.dow = ws.dow AND v.slotCode = ws.slotCode
;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/25eyZuEF)

Comment: Yes, was just missing the `UPDATE`, Thanks! Actually I know the names of the fields, but Zhorov solution does not require to hardcode them, therefore is more flexible.